# tkintermapview PhotoImage object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkintermapview

I am making a project based on tkintermapview, but it throws the error when the following code is run.

```
import tkintermapview as tkmap


        self.map = tkmap.TkinterMapView(self.__map_frame, width=self.__map_width,
                                        height=self.__height, corner_radius=0)
        # google normal tile server
        self.map.set_tile_server("https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga", max_zoom=22)
        # google satellite tile server
        # self.map.set_tile_server("https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga", max_zoom=22)

        # self.map.set_tile_server("http://c.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")  # painting style

        self.map.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.map.set_address("kathmandu")
```

if the last line i.e. set_address() is removed then it runs fine otherwise it throws the error.

following is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7fa9e10ed510>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**I tried the following code as well to reproduce the error**

```
from tkintermapview import TkinterMapView


root_tk = tkinter.Tk()
root_tk.geometry(f"{600}x{400}")
root_tk.title("map_view_simple_example.py")

# create map widget
map_widget = TkinterMapView(root_tk, width=600, height=400, corner_radius=0)
map_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# google normal tile server
map_widget.set_tile_server("https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga", max_zoom=22)

map_widget.set_address("chyasal")

root_tk.mainloop()
```

But this time the error is shown for the first time only. After that the program works correctly.

But again when I change the place to new location say set_address("Manang") again for the first launch, the same error is occured.
But this is not the case with all the places, I tried many different places inside the set_address() method, but only some of them caused the error.

**I have one more question** 
My project should enable a user to pick the pick up and drop off location on the map and the map should calculate the shortest road and its distance(length of road) between the two locations.
**Is tkintermapview good choice or is there a better way to display google map and implement this requirement in tkinter...?**

Comment: _"I have one more question"_ : please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.17 and tkintermapview 1.29.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same error when using tkintermapview, and the flood of messages to stderr is inconsequential but ugly.  My solution was to monkeypatch the PhotoImage.**del** method as follows:

```py
from PIL import ImageTk
def new_img_del(img_self):
    try:
        name = img_self.__photo.name
        img_self.__photo.name = None
        img_self.__photo.tk.call("image", "delete", name)
    except Exception:
        pass
ImageTk.PhotoImage.__del__ = new_img_del
```

This worked for my application, but yours may be different.